# How to easily access anko components within the layout code

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

With Anko, it is easy to access components defined earlier. For example:

```
verticalLayout {
    val name = editText()
    button("Say Hello") {
        onClick { ctx.toast("Hello, ${name.text}!") }
    }
}
```

Since the edit text is defined before the button, its access is easy.
However, when the component you want to access is defined after the current element, is the parent of the current element, or is within a sibling of the current element, I don't know a simple and easy way of accessing it. Here are some examples:

Element defined afterwards

```
verticalLayout {
    button("Say Hello") {
        // how to access "name" here?
    }
    val name = editText()
}
```

Element defined within a sibling

```
verticalLayout {
    verticalLayout {
        val name = editText()
    }
    button("Say Hello") {
        // how to access "name" here?
    }
}
```

Element is a parent

```
val layout = verticalLayout {
    button("Say Hello") {
        // how to access "layout" here?
    }
}
```

If I were to do the same without Anko, with the traditional XML layout files, I could simply refer to those element with `findViewById()`. Is there a simple way of accessing them with Anko?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since Kotlin 1.2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables), you can use [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) for local variables, it could be the solution you need here to get your variables up to the required scope:

Element defined afterwards:

```
verticalLayout {
    lateinit var name: EditText
    button("Say Hello") {
        // use name
    }
    name = editText()
}
```

Element defined within a sibling:

```
verticalLayout {
    lateinit var name: EditText
    verticalLayout {
        name = editText()
    }
    button("Say Hello") {
        // use name
    }
}
```

Element is a parent:

```
lateinit var layout: LinearLayout
layout = verticalLayout {
    button("Say Hello") {
        // use layout
    }
}
```